# Need guidance in R and Python for converting 2 different tables

Tags: python, r, pandas

I want to convert table A into table B. How can I do in Python and R. Are there any specific libraries?

Kindly check the attached image

[image]

Comment: In `R`, you can do `df1 %>% pivot_longer(cols =R3:R5)`

Comment: Thank you. Btw do these tables refer as matrix/list or dataframe and how can we create in R?

Comment: if it is from a excel or csv, you can read with `read.csv` into a data.frame `df1 <- read.csv('yourfile.csv') and then it should work with `pivot_longer`

Comment: "Btw do these tables refer as matrix/list or dataframe" -- without your data (like actual workable data, not a screenshot of a spreadsheet), we don't know the answer to this any better than you do. It's better if you can make a [mcve] and ideally pick one of the two languages you've tagged

Comment: It's not working brother

Answer (score 0):

In `r`, you can use `pivot_longer` function from `tidyr` package:

```r
library(tidyr)
TABLE_B <- pivot_longer(TABLE_A, everything(), names_to = "ITEM Names", values_to = "ALL")
```

Comment: Thank you. Btw do these tables refer as matrix/list or dataframe and how can we create in R?

Comment: They should be data.frames. If you are working on Excel, you can export TableA as csv and read it in R using`read.table` or `read.csv` for example. There is a lot of tutorials online that show you how to import dataset in R.

Comment: It's still not working. I didn't specify the table names such as Table_A and Table_B?
I am getting this error
Error: could not find function "pivot_longer"

Comment: you need to install `tidyr` and load the library.

Comment: I have installed the library

Comment: So, you just need to load it using `library(tidyr)` and the command `pivot_longer` should work.

Comment: Is there anyway to work with dlpyr library? if yes, how can I do that?

Comment: `tidyr` is part of `tidyverse` library as `dplyr`. https://www.tidyverse.org/

Comment: My data is changed now
I am getting this error

> TABLE_B <- pivot_longer(TABLE_A, everything(), names_to = "UPC", values_to = "Product")
Error in unique(names(data)) : object 'TABLE_A' not found

I didn't mention anywhere the Table names

Comment: Where is your dataframe called TABLE_A ? You need to have in your r environment a dataframe called "TABLE_A" to be able to process it.

Comment: Well my real data is similar like that except table names and In the first table there are only 3 columns and some NA values and the new table that I need to create should be 2 columns that will reflect all 3 columns values into 2 columns fields along with removing Na's

Comment: So, you need to replace "TABLE_A" by the name of your current table. To remove `NA`, you can do after having perform the `pivot_longer` command : `TABLE_B <- TABLE_B[!is.na(TABLE_B$ALL),]`

Comment: I am so sorry to bother you again and again. I don't have any table names. I just have headers in the data tables

Comment: How do you load your table in R ? Are you using Rstudio ?

Comment: Yes I am using R studio cloud

Comment: Do you see your tables into the environment section ? How to do you load your tables ?